# passing structure as a void *

Tags: c++, c++11

ALL,

In Foo.h:

```
struct Properties1
{
    std::string name;
    int size;
};

struct Properties2
{
    std::string name1, name2;
    int size1, size2;
}

int my_func(void *param);
```

In Foo.cpp:

```
void *properties;
if( type == 0 )
{
    Properties1 prop;
    prop.name = "abc";
    prop.size = 5;
    properties = &prop;
}
if( type == 1 )
{
    Properties2 prop;
    prop.name1 = "def";
    prop.name2 = "Second property";
    prop.size1 = 8;
    prop.size2 = 10;
    properties = &prop;
}
//    Properties p = *static_cast<Properties *>( properties );
int res = my_func(properties);
```

Properties1 and properties2 are independent structures.

Then my_func will do some processing of the different properties object.

For some reason p object is not valid.

I need to pass different parameters to a function and so wanted to use `void *`.

Or maybe this is easier in C++11?

TIA!!

[EDIT]

So, basically I'm writing a GUI application with different objects that present itself in the window. Every object have its own set of properties.
And I'm allowing the user to edit those properties in the notebook-type dialog. I have multiple pages that popuates themselves from the appropriate properties object.

So the dialog code is constant and it is inside the my_func. However depending on the type of properties I present different set pages.

Basically the my_func is:

```
- Create a dialog (this is inside my_func)
- In the dialog constructor I pass the type and the properties object.
- I create a notebook control and based on the type I add the notebook pages.
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: Accessing `prop`, or a pointer to it, is undefined behaviour once execution has left the if-closure...

Comment: @fredrik, so what is the best way to re-factor? I need to pass different objects depending on the value of type...

Comment: Generally when I want to pass different types to a function, I start with a template. If that doesn't work, I start getting weird, but it usually works. In C++ if you have to go reaching for `void *`, you're probably doing something wrong somewhere else. I need to see more of what you're trying to do to give less generic advice.

Comment: *I need to pass different parameters to a function* -- Either use templates or write an overloaded function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, see an edit. This is the code I'm after - one call for different types. And then in my_func I convert it back and process it.

Comment: @Igor Just have `n` versions of `my_func`, each one taking a property type as a single argument.  `void my_func(Properties1&); void my_func(Properties2&);` etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, well it is a nice solution. Except the processing algorithm is the same - present data to the user and let him/her edit it. The presentation of data is different and it is based on the type. Sorry if that was misleading.

Comment: @Igor C++ doesn't have any sort of reflection, so even in that case you'll need separate functions to determine how to present the different sets of data.  There are ways you could work around that; maybe use a template or virtual function to get some sort of mapping from a string identifier to a function that can present the data to the user, but we would need to know more about what you're doing to give any sort of solution to that problem.

Comment: @MilesBudnek, I just tried to explain what I'm doing. Hopefully you see what I'm after.

Comment: @Igor *- In the dialog constructor I pass the type and the properties object.- I create a notebook control and based on the type I add the notebook pages.* -- IMO this is where things start to break down.  Why is the determination of what to do with the type in the dialog code?  All of that should be encapsulated within an object, and you pass that object to the dialog.  Then call a virtual function within that object that sets things up.  It doesn't matter if `Properties1` and `Properties2` are distinct classes -- each one becomes the responsibility of the object passed into the dialog code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I understand. The problem is that some of them are just simple data structures, while the other are full-blown C++ objects. But I looked over your and Klaus pseudo-code and now I understand what I need to. I will probably use Klaus' solution (no offense, please), simply because I need to get more grip on the templates. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you *need* a `void*` in your program, your design is broken! There are some reasons to still have `void*`, but they are all only valid if you have to deal with old c-style library interfaces. If you write your own functions, it is always wrong to use `void*` without any exception.

> So, basically I'm writing a GUI application with different objects that present itself in the window.

That is exactly the solution you should have! The objects should present *themself*. That means: Don't write code which "knows" something about the object. If you do this, the knowledge of the class or struct is not only in the struct/class, but also in the code which deals with these objects of these class/struct. That is broken design and the exact opposite of OOP.

A typical solution is to have another class which is able to use a common interface and do something on the elements of the objects. The class must provide some information, *which* elements to handle, and the handler object knows *what* to do. So you split the code in two parts, one knows which data to handle and one knows what to do.

In your case you want to have some kind of "editor", so let us try to write a minimal editor example. I did not provide any gui stuff as this lets the code size explode here!

There is a quite common pattern which we call the *serializer*. The basic functionality is to let the objects itself the "which elements" to handle information ( the `Serialize` function ), and the handler classes/objects which do the work `EditSerializer` and `PrintSerializer`.

Now you simply have to provide the handler objects to the objects which should be handled.

Full example:

```
struct Properties1
{
    std::string name;
    int size;

    template < typename Serializer >
        void Serialize( Serializer& ser )
        {
            // Here we only provide the "information" which data we have.
            // at this line of code, we have no idea what a *serializer* 
            // will do with our data.
            ser & name & size;
        }
};

struct Properties2
{
    std::string name1, name2;
    int size1, size2;

    template < typename Serializer >
        void Serialize( Serializer& ser )
        {
            ser & name1 & name2 & size1 & size2; 
        }

};

struct EditSerializer
{
    // Here we don't know which elements we get, but we know
    // what we want to do with all of them!
    // Print them and lets the user enter a new value
    template < typename E > 
    EditSerializer& operator &( E& element ) 
    {   
        std::cout << "Old value:" << element << std::endl; 
        std::cout << "Please enter new value " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> element;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct PrintSerializer
{
    template < typename E >
    PrintSerializer& operator &( E& element )
    {
        std::cout << "Value" << element << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Properties1 p1{"Hallo",100};
    Properties2 p2{"Another","Example",987,456};

    EditSerializer eser;
    p1.Serialize( eser );
    p2.Serialize( eser );

    PrintSerializer pser;
    p1.Serialize( pser );
    p2.Serialize( pser );
}
```

Now you can replace the serializer classes also with your gui components. You can also provide additional tags in your data classes which can provide names or edit field positions or whatever you need.

Remember: The general idea of OOP is to keep all information in one place. So if you maintain your code later, all changes go in one place only and all other code is totally unaffected by that change.

The code uses the `operator &` to write the code smarter as we use a function call. That we use `&` is quite common to the *serializer* pattern. But you can use any operator you like and you can even use a direct function call. The operator usage is a convenience feature.

Comment: so `Serialize()` will call `operator &()` function? How? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Igor: Each of the Serializer classes simply has its "operator&" method. This will be called within the "Serialize" method by simple writing "ser & ...". Please read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: OK, got it. Thx.

Comment: ,I have another question. I have some objects that have a GUI representation for which it will be easier to implement, but some does not depend on the GUI at all - they are just basic struct's. I would prefer to keep them away from GUI. Is there a way to check the object I pass to the template function? Or there is a better way?

Comment: @Igor: Hey, I did a lot of work for you. You did not accept the answer and that is how we "pay" here. It is a bit unfair I believe as you got a lot of help!

Comment: I'm trying to understand and learn  all this code that you and Paul are posted. And I think I will end up with something in the middle. I will upvote both of your answers, though as they are very helpful to understand the semantics of STL and C++11.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code sample could not work due to the lifetime of each object being ended after the `if` block has terminated.

Instead of passing `void *`, you could create an object and pass that to `my_func`.  The `my_func` knows nothing about the internals of each of those objects, except for whatever `public` interface that is provided.

Here is an example.  It uses `virtual` functions, not templates, so this is basically a runtime-based solution.  It differs from the solution @Klaus in that respect.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Properties1
{
    std::string name;
    int size;
};

struct Properties2
{
    std::string name1, name2;
    int size1, size2;
};

struct PropertiesHandler
{
       virtual ~PropertiesHandler() {}
       virtual void HandleProperty() = 0;
};

class PropertiesHandlerProp1 : public PropertiesHandler
{
   Properties1 m_prop;
   public:
       Properties1& getProp() { return m_prop; }
       void HandleProperty() 
       {
          std::cout << m_prop.name << " " << m_prop.size << "\n";
       }
};
      
class PropertiesHandlerProp2 :  public PropertiesHandler
{
   Properties2 m_prop;
   public:
       Properties2& getProp() { return m_prop; }
       void HandleProperty() 
       {
          std::cout << m_prop.name1 << " " << m_prop.size1 << "\n" << m_prop.name2 << " " << m_prop.size2 << "\n";
       }
};

int my_func(std::unique_ptr<PropertiesHandler>& ptr)
{
     // Create the dialog
     //... 
     // Call handling function
     ptr->HandleProperty();
     //...
     return 1;
}

int main()
{  
    std::unique_ptr<PropertiesHandler> propPtr;
    int type = 1;
    if( type == 0 )
    {
        auto ptr = std::make_unique<PropertiesHandlerProp1>(); 
        auto& prop = ptr->getProp();
        prop.name = "abc";
        prop.size = 10;
        propPtr = std::move(ptr);
   }
   else
   if( type == 1 )
   {
        auto ptr = std::make_unique<PropertiesHandlerProp2>(); 
        auto& prop = ptr->getProp();
        prop.name1 = "def";
        prop.name2 = "Second property";
        prop.size1 = 8;
        prop.size2 = 10;

        propPtr = std::move(ptr);
  }
  my_func(propPtr);  // this will use the second property
}
```

Output:

```
def 8
Second property 10
```

Note that `my_func` knows nothing about `name1`, `name2`, etc.  It doesn't even know that it is handling a `PropertiesHandlerProp2` object.  It shouldn't know these things -- all that information is within the respective objects.

Comment: I'm working with C++11, and not C++14, where unique_ptr is introduced. I will update at some point. Could you tell me how do I check for C++14 support in my code. I did find the implementation of this functiion, and so will put the check there. TIA!!

Comment: the error I receive is `error: ‘make_unique’ is not a member of 'std' - note: suggested alternative:'‘__unique'`

Comment: `std::make_unique` is C++14.  Otherwise you need to use `auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<PropertiesHandlerProp1>(new PropertiesHandlerProp1);`, for example.

Answer (score -1):

```
Properties *p2 = new Propertes;
p2->name = "abc";
p2->size = 5;
properties = p2;
// don't forget to delete p at some point!
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it answers the question. Please consider editing your answer to explain how this code solves the problem in the question, so that it is useful not just for the OP but also other users with the same issue.